# Bluetooth Audio Re routing - Separate Input and Output Dongle - Pi B+ AND Micro Bluetooth USB-Stick V4.0, ASUS USB-BT400

Tags: usb, audio, bluetooth

I recently thought about doing this:
- Building a Bluetooth Audio Gateway for my home.
Background:
- I have an Bluetooth Audio Sink in my Kitchen, my living room and on the balcony. 
- When I listen to music from my ubuntu laptop and want to switch from kitchen to living room, i have to reconnect to the specific sink. 
- Since BT Audio is one with a very low latency, I would like to use this solution.

Now the idea in detail:
- The pi will get 2 or more Bluetooth Dongle. One is the input, the rest is output. 
- Each output dongle is connected to a fix sink.
- On the pi I want to switch/enable/disable each output, so I can choose the specific output via some script (this is easy then).

The question:
- How can I configure each dongle and the Pi itself to work like this?
   - How can I configure a specific BT Dongle to work as A2DP-SRC or A2DP-SNK?

Thanks in advance!!! :)

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer your question about configuring BT dongles, but I had the same desire a few years ago. I ripped all my music (and my wife's music) to the media server. I could play music in every room, but as I walked around the house, each room played different music.

My solution at that time was to start multicast streaming the music over my LAN using gstreamer. Then in each room, the computer attached to the television (I used MythTV) could be "tuned" to a music channel. I even have a Christmas channel for holiday music.

Since I discovered the raspberry PI, I have expanded my music capabilities from three clients to many. For < $40 I can add a new client device, assuming an amplifier and speakers are already present in an area. I have an SD card image that will automatically start playing music and button connections to switch channels.

The music plays without having to carry a laptop around. The laptop could stream to RPi's from anywhere within WiFi range.

Comment: Thx for the fast answer.

I already tried multicast streams. Despite the drawback of a bigger latency the main problem was/is, that it uses my normal network an when much data is move here, the sound gets bad or latency gets even higher, so I wanted a separate, standalone method of transportation.